# How to build a loop to import many dataframes and modify them in the same way?

Tags: r, database, loops

I have one dataframe of news for each month from january 1996 to december 2018, which means 264 dataframes. They all have the same structure and I need to modify them in the same way. For example, my code for one dataframe is more or less the following:

```
#import data (only one column $V1)
News.9601 <- read.delim("D:/Reuters/1996/News.RTRS.199601.0210.txt.gz", header=FALSE,quote = "") 

#split the first columns in more variables
News.9601 = News.9601 %>% 
  mutate(v2=lapply(strsplit(as.character(V1), "\"mimeType\""), "[", 2))

#select only those news that include "R:"
news.9601=news.9601[grepl('R:',news.9601$v2),]


#select only those news that include certain "tags" in $v2

for(i in 1:30){
  tags_split1=paste(tags_split[[i]],collapse = "|")
  tags_split1=gsub("[[:space:]]", "", tags_split1)
  nam=paste("A", i, sep = "")

  assign(nam,news.9601[grepl(tags_split1,news.9601$v2,perl = T),]
         )
}
news.9601=rbind(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10,A11,A12,A13,A14,A15,A16,A17,
                 A18,A19,A20,A21,A22,A23,A24,A25,A26,A27,A28,A29,A30)

news.9601=news.9601[!duplicated(news.9601),]

#Some text analysis, rx.app is a matching rule
news.9601 = news.9601 %>%
  mutate(approach <- regmatches(title_body, gregexpr(rx.app, v2, perl=TRUE)),
         approach=lengths(approach))

write.csv(news.9601, file = "news.9601.csv")
rm(news.9601)
```

This is what I have to do for every month-data, except for the dataframe name "D:/Reuters/1996/News.RTRS.199601.0210.txt.gz" in which both the year "/1996/" and the file name change according to the month and year.

Is there some way to import and run the code above for all my months-data in a loop, rather than re-writing the same code for 264 times?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tdel thanks this might work, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: I will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work

```
files <- list.files(path="folderpath/", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
```

`files` store all the file names in that folder, than loop that files one by one

```
for (file in files){

 }
```

Comment: thanks. Using your loop, how can I save each file under a separate name? Just doing, e.g. ` write.csv(file, file = "file.csv") ` would work?

Comment: just use `paste0` like this `write.csv(df, paste0(file,".csv"))`  where `df` is the final df that you would like to save and  `file` in paste0 is used to save the file with different names

Answer (score 1):

Here the code you may use, using a liste of file.

```
Format_Funtion <- function(mypath, mylist) {
    mydata <- read.delim(paste0(mypath, mylist),header=FALSE,quote = "")

    #split the first columns in more variables
    mydata <- mydata %>% 
        mutate(v2=lapply(strsplit(as.character(V1), "\"mimeType\""), "[", 2))

    #select only those news that include "R:"
    mydata=mydata[grepl('R:',mydata$v2),]

    #select only those news that include certain "tags" in $v2
    for(i in 1:30){
        tags_split1=paste(tags_split[[i]],collapse = "|")
        tags_split1=gsub("[[:space:]]", "", tags_split1)
        nam=paste("A", i, sep = "")

        assign(nam,mydata[grepl(tags_split1,mydata$v2,perl = T),])
    }

    mydata=rbind(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10,A11,A12,A13,A14,A15,A16,A17,
             A18,A19,A20,A21,A22,A23,A24,A25,A26,A27,A28,A29,A30)

    mydata=mydata[!duplicated(mydata),]

    #Some text analysis, rx.app is a matching rule
mydata = mydata %>%
        mutate(approach <- regmatches(title_body, gregexpr(rx.app, v2, perl=TRUE)),
           approach=lengths(approach))

    write.csv(mydata, file = paste0(sub(".txt.gz", "", mylist), ".csv"))
}
```

You can add the path for a output directory in the last line of code if needed.

```
mypath <- "D:/Reuters/1996/" 
mylist <- list.files(path=mypath, pattern="txt.gz$")
lapply(Format_Function, mypath, mylist)
```

Comment: thanks! and then ` lapply(mylist, Format_function) ` right?

Comment: Yep, sorry for the typo, tell me if that work, I wrote it without the data I could not check if this was ok for yours. Also, the list file method above works if all files are in the same folder